# how to get country list in english (en_US) language on woocommerce checkout page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook, country-codes

I want to get country list which is in English language on Woocommerce Checkout page regardless the site language (for example Chinese or Japanese).

is it possible?

※ Edit note:
no multi-lang plugin used. that's only one language site. but client wants to show english version country list no matter what the site language is.

Comment: which plugin you are using for multi-language?

Comment: @purvik7373 no multi-lang plugin used. that's only one language site. but client wants to show english version country list no matter what the site language is.